# Props should contain an interface - how to define that

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, I want one of my components to have an Interface passed to it. My approach was this

```
import { InterfaceType } from "typescript";

type Props = {
    dataType: InterfaceType
}

export default function CreateRow(props: Props) {
  return (
    <div>"test"</div>
  );  
}
```

and the call to the component

```
        <CreateRow dataType={ISchool}/>
```

But I get

```
'ISchool' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Edit:
In CreateRow, I want to create objects of the type dataType which will come from the Props. The interface that will be passed through Props.dataType will be used in CreateRow to create objects of that type.

Comment: ISchool should be your value(object).interface/type checking should be applied for createRow

Comment: I don't understand :) can you show me? In my code I meant to pass that interface, not a value which implements it.

Comment: "I want one of my components to have an Interface passed to it." Please say more about what this means. What does "pass an interface" mean to you? Are you asking how you would pass an object to `dataType`? Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBy5Dw)? Or do you want any interface to `CreateRow` and then `dataType` would be constrained by that dynamic type?

Comment: May I ask why you are passing a data type as a prop instead of importing it?

Comment: @AlexWayne I added an explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rethink your approach here.

Props are runtime values. However, types exist only at compile time. This means you *cannot* pass a type as a prop.

That's what this error means:

> 'ISchool' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

`ISchool` is a type, and does not exist when the code is actually running. So passing as a prop can't work.

---

What you can do is make `CreateRow` a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions). This lets it be aware of a specific type, and enforce that you use that type in its props.

For example:

```
type Props<T> = {
    rowData: T
}

export default function CreateRow<T>(props: Props<T>) {
  return (
    <div>"test"</div>
  );  
}
```

Which you might use like:

```
const testA = <CreateRow<AbcNum> rowData={{ abc: 123 }} /> // fine
const testB = <CreateRow<AbcNum> rowData={{ abc: 'asd' }} /> // type error

// or

const CreateAbcNumRow = CreateRow<AbcNum>
const testC = <CreateAbcNumRow rowData={{ abc: 123 }} /> // fine
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=65&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChzSYBPMJOABRzAGcAeAFQD44BeOAb1JxhcHAHcAIihgoAXHHakAvuSQAPSLDgATJJhQBXADZYDAOwzAIZuAGEi0pAghiOnABRgmzeYwgs3AEoBIVEkGAMoG3dQ4VZtYAA3TgAiGCRmGBTWAHoE5NDAgG5hZQpyYDN0qH00OgBBACM0ADkDPH44FGb5M3bGpCg4FVI0a0y4dMz63jhWe1R051cm1vbucSkZHn5O7rR5AEYAJgBmYaU4HO4cnLhMSqRR8fgpmAAhWfmHJZdWVbaIA2Li2KB2ex6BBQzG0+AuVxud2otDggxwUHItzg0HIYzMEwWjgB7WWs0JvxWzUBnGe+NeGRgti+5KQxJApM20jBuy6kJO5yUl2uVzuDzMTyAA)